# Cannot rewrite recursive call: it is not in tail position

Tags: scala, dotty, scala-3

I've been playing with Dotty and tried to implement a simple List. This is how I've implemented it:

```
enum List[+A] {
  case Cons(head :A, tail: List[A])
  case Nil extends List[Nothing]
}
```

The issue I'm having is that this implementation fails to compile with `Cannot rewrite recursive call: it is not in tail position`:

```
@tailrec
def drop[A](n: Int, as: List[A]): List[A] = 
  (n,as) match
    case (0, _) => as
    case (_, Nil) => Nil
    case (x, Cons(_, tail)) => drop(x-1, tail)
```

On a different file I tried the same implementation, with standard library's List, and it compiles:

```
@tailrec
def drop[A](n: Int, as: List[A]): List[A] = 
  (n,as) match
    case (0, _) => as
    case (_, Nil) => Nil
    case (x, _ :: tail) => drop(x-1, tail)
```

Maybe I'm just tired and not seeing the obvious error, but maybe there's something else here? Any weirdness caused by that `extends List[Nothing]` I had to add to make the code compile?

Thanks!

**EDIT**:

- [My code that leads to the compilation error](https://gitlab.com/rmsam/stackoverflow-tailrec/-/tree/14b38def89b0bc5b8ea385e17fe2305d44e6f1b9)

Comment: Try making that drop `final`.

Comment: Like in changing the signature to `final def drop[A](n: Int, as: List[A]): List[A]`? That didn't work

Comment: Uhm, then it seems like a bug. I would try reporting it. Or maybe asking [here](https://users.scala-lang.org/) first.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. With your code, I get numerous type errors which have nothing to do with `@tailrec`. Also, one of the type errors is referring to `collection.immutable.Nil`, indicating that your types might not be what you think they are.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Probably you didn't `import List.{Nil, Cons}` (if necessary you can't unimport `import collection.immutable.{Nil => _}`).

Comment: @DmytroMitin: Thanks. That was stupid of me. However, now it compiles fine *with* `@scala.annotation.tailrec`, so still not reproducible.

Comment: @RA. What's your version of Dotty? I can't reproduce. In Dotty 0.25.0-bin-20200429-c5a76f0-NIGHTLY your code seems to compile.

Comment: @JörgWMittag right, the same to me.

Comment: Thanks all. I can share my code soon (no access to laptop now) and the version of Dotty. The drop method is inside the List enum's companion object, if that helps.

Answer (score 3):

In Dotty 0.25.0-bin-20200429-c5a76f0-NIGHTLY

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

enum List[+A] {
  case Cons(head :A, tail: List[A])
  case Nil extends List[Nothing]

  @tailrec
  def drop[A](n: Int, as: List[A]): List[A] =
    (n,as) match
      case (0, _) => as
      case (_, Nil) => Nil
      case (x, Cons(_, tail)) => drop(x-1, tail)
}
```

produces

```
TailRec optimisation not applicable, method drop is neither private nor final so can be overridden
```

If you make `drop` final or private the code compiles.

Comment: So I was using Dotty version `0.23.0-RC1` but the problem completely went away once I've upgraded to `0.24.0-RC1`. It works even without the `final`.

Comment: It is important to note, however, that in order for an expression to be considered a *constant expression*, it is *not* enough for the `val` to be implicitly `final` or `private`, it *must* be *explicitly* annotated as `private final val`. So, the fact that something is *implicitly* `final` is not in *all* circumstances equivalent to being *explicitly* `final`, even though it is the case for tail recursion elimination.